# printing booklet from PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I am trying to print a booklet out of PDF file to 2-sided A4 pages using Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro.

it always get stuck at 100% and printer wont print last page.
I tried it with Adobe reader. Booklet printing from office docs is working fine so I think this issue isn't related to printer. 
any solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

It isn't free, but [FinePrint](http://fineprint.com/fp/) may work.

[image]

Comment: Love FinePrint, been using it for years.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **printer** properties to print two document pages on one paper page. That way you're not using Acrobat.

Comment: hi thanks but this is not working, i have tried settings with printer properties and adobe properties both alone and together but this wont work. any other solution

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Scott suggested you could use [Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info) but like FinePrint it is also not free (30-day trial):

If you go to the Channel configuration, you can set the **Pages on 1 sheet:** to the number **2** or **4** and then you can click the label to enable "**Create booklet**":

[image]